# How to paste text only data to OneNote 2013?

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-onenote

Is there a keyboard shortcut to insert "Text Only" data to OneNote2013?

[image]

Maybe I can assign map keyboard shortcut using macro which could work in most Office products?

- This is [not really an option](http://cybertext.wordpress.com/2012/11/21/word-2010-keyboard-shortcut-to-paste-unformatted-text/) because it's multiple keyboard combinations:

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have a context menu key on your keyboard this can be accomplished with 2 presses.

I am sorry I cannot include a picture. It is located between the Windows Key and Ctrl on the right side next to the arrow keys.

The context menu will open and then you can press "T" this will perform the operation using only the keyboard at the location of the cursor.

Answer (score 16):

Found the answer here: [Set the default paste in OneNote as "Keep Text Only"](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-onenote/can-i-set-the-default-paste-in-onenote-as-keep/92f552ec-7042-4296-ac69-e74ad8791e2a)

In short,

1. Paste with Ctrl+V
2. Open "Paste Option" that appears at the right bottom of the pasted text.
3. Select plain text icon
4. Open "Paste Option" again and click "Set as Default Paste"

Comment: This is exactly what i am looking for

Comment: if you do ctr+V follow by pressing the ctrl button, the paste option will appear automatically

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively use AutoHotkey (https://autohotkey.com) with the following script block. This filters to only apply the shortcut if OneNote is active and in this case detects CTRL + SHIFT + V and translates it into ALT + H V T for paste keep text only.

```
#IfWinActive ahk_exe ONENOTE.EXE
^+v::
SendInput !hvt
Return
#IfWinActive
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure which version I have but if you paste and the little ctrl box comes up you can press the downward arrow, then select paste plain text, again go to the ctrl box and you can then press default paste.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the best AutoHotkey code I could come up with for the OneNote app that comes with Office 365. Note that the filter will select all Metro/Modern/Universal/Windows Store apps.

```
; Office 365 OneNote Metro app hotkeys
#IfWinActive ahk_class ApplicationFrameWindow

; "Text Only" paste in OneNote
^+v::
  SendInput, {appskey}
  Sleep, 100
  SendInput, {right}
  Sleep, 100
  SendInput, {down}{down}{enter}
return

#IfWinActive
```